# Modify form values before creating node

Tags: forms, nodes

I would like to use user-submitted data from one form field and add it to anther field, then submit the form to create a node that has my custom data. I'm having a hard time doing this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: create your form for create node and change value before saving node.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what the node api hooks are good for.

From the docs:

> The node passed validation and is about to be saved. Modules may use
>   this to make changes to the node before it is saved to the database.

You don't specify D6 or D7

[**In D6**](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6)

[hook_nodeapi()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) $op == 'presave'

[**In D7**](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/group/node_api_hooks/7)

[hook_node_presave()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7)

You can modify values in your implementations of these hooks and they will be saved.

*edit*

If you need the NID you have to use hook_node_insert, but you will have to save to the DB directly.

Comment: D7. The problem I'm running into is this: I need to use the node's nid to populate a node reference field (referencing a different entity with the same id #). However, it appears that the nid field isn't populated until the node is saved. Perhaps I need to reload the node once it is saved?

Comment: Edited, with solution, but trying to keep IDs in sync is a very tricky way to go. If one gets created but the other doesn't your site will break.

Comment: Hmm - adding node_save($node) to hook_node_insert seems to cause a PDO exception - duplicate entry

Comment: but you will have to save to the DB directly...

Comment: OK, not with node_save() but rather db_insert() I'll give this a try thanks for your help.